# CollapsingToolbarLayout scrolling behavior on tablets

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

There's an issue with the CollapsingToolbarLayout on tablets when scrolling NestedScrollView that contains small number of views

the issue is that the toolbar collapses even after the the scrolling stops.

[image]

you can reproduce the issue source code: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: it behaves similarly on phones also. I had same issues when I put NestedScrollview with very less content. Have you found any solution on this?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in the `v22.2.1` release of the Design Library. If I'm not wrong, now the content "follows" the toolbar and there's no ugly space between the two.